# Firefox fail to trigger jQuery event

Tags: jquery, firefox, triggers

Following code triggers an event when clicking an anchor.
The event should be captured on the second function to launch an alert.
The code succeeds on Google Chrome, but fails on Firefox 36.0.1
Does anybody sees where is the problem?

```
<a href='#'>clic here</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(document).trigger('RaiseHelloWorld', {});
        });

        $(document).on('RaiseHelloWorld', function (e, argument) {
            alert('Hello World!');
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried  ` $(document).trigger('RaiseHelloWorld')`

Comment: It's working fine for me, with or without the useless `,{}` http://jsfiddle.net/s5yeeLrb/

Comment: Its working fine for me, You're storing output of callback function in `e` in `$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {`and you're using it as `event` `event.preventDefault();`, that could be the issue, try changing the either one.

Comment: Check this `fiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/jt1w1ach/

Comment: You're right, but here, there's nothing to prevent. The link doesn't have a URL, and it's not a submit button.

Comment: @JeremyThille will prevent hash being added to url as well as a page jump to top as a result of unfound hash

Comment: Okay but anyway, that's not what's preventing the code from working.

Comment: You are right, Moksh! I removed event,preventDefault(); and it works in both Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: The funny thing is that the Fiddle works in both without removing event.preventDefault . Thanks everybody!